# When I run the solution it opens not the default page in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routeconfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

}

I don't know why it has opened `http://localhost:00000/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml` in this location

What can do that?

Comment: do you have web essential installed in your vs ?

Comment: go to properties of your project and remove the set specific page

Comment: Write it down so that I can reply to highlight that the real answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

1) Right click on your project solution

2) Select Property

3) Select Web option and then Select Current Page

Answer (score 0):

Hello use this code.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "YourProjectDLLName.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

Make Sure don't forget to add namespace of your project DLL.
after do this build your project and debug.